# Django Generic Relation woth parent model

Tags: python, django, django-models, generic-relations, django-generic-relations

I have created a model `Comments`. I want store reply in same table `Comment`.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

  content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

  # Relation
  reply = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='reply')
  like = GenericRelation(Like, related_query_name='like')
```

Here i am getting this error !!

```
  reply = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='reply')
  NameError: name 'Comment' is not defined
```

How can i set this relationship ?

Comment: I'd have a look at 'self' instead of Comment, in the reply line. https://stackabuse.com/recursive-model-relationships-in-django/

Comment: I can't reverse it. `c = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)` `c.reply.all()` it returns `<QuerySet []>` But i have replies in this comment.

Comment: You must have had a typo when creating the comment. Create a new question with code sample (the one that creates the link in view and the models)

Comment: Can you give an example ??

Comment: Well, something like c= Comment(reply=comment_to_reply_to) then c.save()

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error, because `Comment` is not defined yet.

Replace

```
reply = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='reply')
```

with

```
reply = GenericRelation('self', related_query_name='reply')
```

Comment: How can i reverse it ??

Comment: `c = Comment.objects.get(pk=1)` `c.reply.all()` it returns `<QuerySet []>` But i have replies in this comment.